# Rest API (Consumer is not authorized to access %resources)

Tags: magento2.2

I know this question was already asked very often, but I got a little different kind of problem.
At first I´m just trying to get normal categories via rest api and I fail.

I installed local Magento 2.2.2 and everything works fine.

I installed same version on webserver and everytime I try to receive the categories via rest api I get, that consumer is not authorized.

I can definitely make sure that:
- I connect via admin and admin has all rights for access on all api endpoints (I also created a single apiuser and gave him all rights and another tiem just right for catalog/categories and so on)
- I already read every post found to that topic with that normal solutions like token is expired and stuff...
- I receive a token from "index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token".
- I checked everything, no kidding twenty times, compared to working local installation and webserver installation.
- Local works fine (normal xampp environment), webserver refuses to acceppt admin rights.

On Local install everything is okay, I already imported all my categories via rest api on local, but on my webserver - everything I tried just fails.
I received categories via anonymous access but that doesn´t help posting categories and that was everything that worked.

I already suspected some problems with apache, because I have no access to apache and php installation but I can give my webserver provider a ticket if something would be a problem with apache.

If anybody has any kind of idea please let me know, I´m really looking for a solution to that problem. I´m desperate now.

Best Regards,
Loqic

Comment: were you able to resolve?

Comment: I could resolve now.
Could have been a problem with "allow_url_fopen" in Apache maybe.
But I´m not absolutely sure. Webserver Provider changed that in Apache and afterwards the API was accessible